# NameError: name '_text' is not defined. Did you mean: 'next'?

Tags: python

```
import turtle

pen=turtle.Turtle()

def curve():
    for i in range(200):
        pen.right(1)
        pen.forward(1)

def heart():
    pen.fillcolor('red')
    pen.begin_fill()
    pen.left(140)
    pen.forward(113)
    curve()
    pen.left(120)
    curve()
    pen.forward(112)
    pen.end_fill()

    def _text():
        pen.up()
        pen.setpos(-68, 95)
        pen.down()
        pen.color('yellow')
        pen.write("I Love You")

heart()
_text()
pen.ht()
```

help would be great ty!

i made a function i have it definded even tho it says it's not

i fixed it

...............................................................

Comment: Look at your definition for `_test()`. Does it look any different from the other function definitions?

Comment: Your `_test()` function is indented too much. Indentations matter in Python. The way you have it written right now is that the _test() function is part of the `heart()` function. So either move the `_text()` function to the left or call it inside `heart()`.

Comment: ok i will try. ok that did work but now i have all these errors

Comment: File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Documents\python 3.11.1\Lib\turtle.py", line 1679, in right
    self._rotate(-angle)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Documents\python 3.11.1\Lib\turtle.py", line 3293, in _rotate
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Documents\python 3.11.1\Lib\turtle.py", line 2661, in _update
    self._update_data()

Answer (score 1):

Your `_text` function is inside the `heart` function. So, it is only visible in the scope of the `heart` function. It is not visible outside the `heart` function, so you could not call it.

You can fix it by just unindenting the entire function so the `_text` function is global:

```
def heart():
    pen.fillcolor('red')
    pen.begin_fill()
    pen.left(140)
    pen.forward(113)
    curve()
    pen.left(120)
    curve()
    pen.forward(112)
    pen.end_fill()

def _text():
    pen.up()
    pen.setpos(-68, 95)
    pen.down()
    pen.color('yellow')
    pen.write("I Love You")
```